# rename theorem environment to proposition

Tags: sectioning, formatting, theorems

How can I rename the theorem environment to proposition? In other words, I would like to print:

Proposition 1 instead of Theorem 1/Lemma 1, etc

Thanks in advance

PS: I am using koma-script article

Comment: Do you want to maintain your current code (which probably uses `\begin{theorem}` ... `\end{theorem}`), or create a new environment that prints `Proposition` instead of `Theorem`? Are you using any theorem-related packages?

Comment: I would like to create a new environment that prints `Proposition`. I am using `amsmath` package

Comment: For future reference, this is information you should typically supply to the community as part of the question.

Comment: @Yorgos -- `amsmath` has nothing to do with theorems.  `amsthm` is the relevant package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
```

in your preamble, then

```
\begin{prop}
Blah blah
\end{prop}
```

in the body of the document.