# Definitions style

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I need your help to get this style[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280387/rename-theorem-environment-to-proposition

Comment: Also for the future, please provide an `MWE` with stuff you have tried ;-)